# How to create user audit logging using Java8

Tags: java, spring

as we have in spring+jpa to audit user details like createdBy,updatedBy, createdDate, updatedDate.
i want to perform similar functionality but without spring+jpa annotations as my project uses java8 not sure if we will have use hibernate/jpa.
so whenever persistent object(in dao layer) is created/ready , want to ensure these values are populated dynamically instead of manual invocation.

Comment: Can you refine your requirement further? What is your tech stack? How did you use to achieve this earlier?

Comment: DId you heard of or tried envers library? this can help you.

Comment: envers works with hibernate only not with plain java

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotation from javax.persistence in your entity as:

```
@PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    creationTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    changeTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
  }
```

so whenever you save or update your entity it automatically manage insertion or updation of respected columns

Comment: my requirement doesnt have JPA, i have this solution if i want to use JPA, pls see my question again, thanks.